# Checking connection request and forward to another program

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, udp, ip

I want to know if its possible program1 and program2 listen to the same port,but program1 receive the request first and then forward the request to program2.

thanks,

PS:If possible is there any C++ example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No and Yes.  Only one program can listen on a given port but you *can* pass an open connection from one process to another in Unix.

A [Google search](http://google.com/search?q=pass%20socket%20over%20unix%20pipe) will give you articles on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for 2 programs to listen on the same port. If you want to forward input to another process, the simplest way would be putting it on stdout and then using a pipe "|" on the command line. The other process could just read it from stdin.

You could also open a second socket.